# Is it possible to get a full list of windows of running apps?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsworkspace

I'm trying to obtain a list of running applications on macOS to do some window manipulation on fullscreen apps to be specific.

First I'm obtaining list of all running apps via `[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace].runningApplications` then I'm using Accessibility API to get the windows:

```
AXUIElementCopyAttributeValues((__bridge AXUIElementRef) app,
                               (__bridge CFStringRef) kAXWindowsAttribute,
                               index,
                               count,
                               &values);
```

It looks like this is the way to go but for apps that have full-screen windows the `kAXWindowsAttribute` is empty. For non-full-screen windows it works just fine.

Comment: `runningApplications` *does* appear to include apps running full-screen (in limited tests). Edit your question to show your code and explain what's its going wrong in more detail. Hopefully someone can then help you.

Comment: Your problem appears to be nothing to do with full-screen windows *per se*, rather it is to do with windows in a *different space*. Try opening an app in a different space and running your code, unless your code is running in the same space you won't get the windows. I suspect this is tied in with Apple's strong view that there should be no (public) programmatic interface to switch spaces, but you'll have to figure that out. HTH

Answer (score 2):

The Core Graphics Services API can provide a list of all windows via the CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo() function.

Comment: Can I manipulate (exit fullscreen/minimize) the windows using the same API?

Comment: Nope. But you might be able to use the accessibility API for that, once you have the window ids.